# Android: obtaining the all available intent extras of a Google Drive activity

Tags: android, android-intent, google-drive-api

We want to know if is possible obtain all the available intent extras in an activity of an application.
We are doing an Android application that make an explicit intent to the Google Drive activity that upload a file, selecting the gmail account and a Google Drive folder.

We need the our application select the folder and the account, not the user (the user would can select it easyly picking in the available folders and accounts, but we not want it).

We were seeing which extras can add in the intent in order to do that, but the unique extra that "interact" whit the Google Drive activity is the extra EXTRA_STREAM, which provides the stream of the file that we want to upload:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM

We see also that exists a metod intent.getExtras(), which return a map (Bundle) whit all the extras of an intent, but there are all the extras previously added, not the availables.

We not find more standard extras that interact whit the Google Drive activity, but probably the source code of the application have defined extras in order to make this (unfortunately the Google Drive application is not open source).

This is the code we have for now:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "MESSAGE";


  private void error(String message){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
  }


public void sendMessage(View view){
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

   intent.setType("text/plain");
   String rootPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(rootPath.concat("/rev.txt")));
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "asunto");
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");
   String[] emails = new String[4];
   emails[0] = "aa@gmail.com";
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emails);

    List<ResolveInfo> apps = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

    System.out.println(apps.size());


    if (apps.size()>0) {

        ResolveInfo ri;
        for (Iterator<ResolveInfo> it = apps.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            ri = it.next();
            System.out.println(ri.toString());
        }
        ComponentName component = new ComponentName("com.google.android.apps.docs",
                "com.google.android.apps.docs.shareitem.UploadSharedItemActivity");

        intent.setComponent(component);

        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("NON ATOPO O DRIVE");
            error("NON ATOPO O DRIVE");
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("non hai aplicacions");
        error("non hai aplicacions");
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> We want to know if is possible obtain all the available intent extras in an activity of an application.

Read the documentation supplied by the author of the activity in question. If there is no such documentation, do not start the activity.

If you are expecting to be able to collect information about supported extras programmatically, that is not possible.